# MVC 3, C# - invalid column name generated by code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to asp.net C# and trying to learn by building a simple web app based on MVC 3 Music application. So far i have had a decent run but i am running into this this and i am not able to figure out the root cause. plz help

I am building a simple website where Projects are listed, then clicking on projects you see all the tables and then clicking on table you see all the columns. Projects/Tables/Column are being fetched from SQL db which has valid data and PK/FK keys defined. i am able to navigate from projects to tables and can see all columns under tables but when I click on column link, i get error as described below.

ERROR: "Invalid column name 'Tables_Id'."  SQL profiler shows this column in the query but i do not understand where is it coming from as I do not have any such columm.

CONTROLLER CLASS

```
public class ProjectController : Controller  // Inherit from base class Controller
{
    DbEntities storeDB = new DbEntities();   //Create Object/instance of class //StorDB is  reference to an object

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Name = storeDB.ProjectNM.ToList(); //Use 'var' coz we may have any type returned, 'var' is determined at run time
        return View(Name); 
    }

    public ActionResult BrowseTables(string Projects) 
    {
        var ProjectModel = storeDB.ProjectNM.Include ("Tabless")
        .Single(g => g.Name == Projects);

        return View(ProjectModel);
    }

    public ActionResult BrowseColumns(string TableIs)
    {
        var ProjectModel1 = storeDB.TableNM.Include("Columnss")
        .Single(g => g.Tbl_Name == TableIs);

        return View(ProjectModel1);

        //var ColumnModel = storeDB.TableNM.Find(TableIs);
       // return View(ColumnModel);

    }
}
```

Other Classes

```
public partial class Projects //Partial class, see comment below
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Tables> Tabless { get; set; }  //Navigation Property, required so that we can include tables under projects

}

public class Tables
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Tbl_Name { get; set; }
    public Projects Project { get; set; }   //Class table can have (belong) only one project

    public List<Columns> Columnss { get; set; } //Table can have more than one column
  }

 public class Columns
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Tables")] 
    public int TblId { get; set; }
    public string Column_Name { get; set; }
    public string IncludeFlag { get; set; }
  }
```

View

```
<ul> 
@foreach (var Tables in Model.Tabless) 
{ 
    <li> 
      @Html.ActionLink(Tables.Tbl_Name, "BrowseColumns", new { TableIs = Tables.Tbl_Name }) 
    </li> 
}
```

---

Query from SQL profiler

```
[Project2].[Tables_Id] AS [Tables_Id]
```

As you can seethe query has a column  [Tables_Id] and I do nto understand why it is there as i do nto have any such column. Please help!

Comment: not sure exactly why it happening because I do not see your database design in your sql server but check the names and make sure that the names of your model variables are same as in you sql server it seems like the problem may be related to naming.

Comment: As far as DB is concerned, i have three tables (1) Projects (2) Tables (3) Columns. They have same columns as defined in the class above. 'Tables' have a column (ProjectID) which is FK to ID in table 'Projects' and 'Columns' have a column (TblID) which is FK to ID in tables.

Comment: Just so you know, the type of a 'var' is determined at compile time. Not run time. You can use a dynamic to hold whatever type you want at run time.

Comment: @user1102621 did you find a suitable answer to flag?

Comment: One.beat  yes I did, please see my last comment....pasting here again..."THANK YOU ALL - This finally worked, as you all have suggested I had to make sure that my column names are defined correctly as per EF4.1 norms. I renamed column TblId to TABLEID and everythign now works, should have caught this intially but never thought that I need to follow key naming conventiosn this strictly. "

Comment: @user1102621 If you are satisfied with an answer, please mark it so that they provider gets his/her reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Basically MVC3 and EF4 do a lot of things on convention.

My suggestion to make things a little clearer for yourself is read up on EF 4.1 a little, and let it pluralize your table names for you, and use the data annotations (or property mapping if you don't like the attributes in your model) to mark your object's Id properties...

This is not necessarily the cause of your problem, but I think you will find it a lot easier to see what is going on in your profiler and models when the names/values make more logical sense.

Start by singularizing your objects: Table, Column, etc. or even using a more descriptive name... again if for no other reason it will be easier for you to read and debug, or even to get better answers here.

Answer (score 2):

The convention for EF4.1 and foreign keys is to name them `{TableName}_{ColumnName}` so your foreign key to Tables is expecting a column names `Table_Id` (because Table is the name of the table, and Id is the name of the PK column.

This might help: [EF 4.1 messing things up. Has FK naming strategy changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344474/ef-4-1-messing-things-up-has-fk-naming-strategy-changed)

Comment: THANK YOU ALL - This finally worked, as you all have suggested I had to make sure that my column names are defined correctly as per EF4.1 norms. I renamed column TblId to TABLEID and everythign now works, should have caught this intially but never thought that I need to follow key naming conventiosn this strictly. Thanks again